# How to troubleshoot identity verification issue when requesting credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-score

I have a long credit history (slightly more than 2 years) and so far I have no success in requesting my free credit report. There is a small caveat, I am successfully able to verify my identity at one of the three agencies, but the same exact information draws a blank at the other two. I do know that my credit history exists at the other two as a third-party free credit report service can get my information without any difficulty.

What steps can I take to rectify this such as:
- Contacting the agency?
- Requesting by mail?
- Try again later?
- Sanity check the provided information?

Comment: Contacting the agencies seems both necessary and sufficient ...

Comment: What do you mean "draws a blank"? I think what usually happens in that case is the page says something like "we can't get your report online, fill out the following form and mail it in". They don't actually tell you the reason why.

Comment: 3 years is not "long".